# Economic Fact or Fact of Economics?

Tags: grammar, word-order, construction

Demand will rise when prices fall is a *basic economic fact/basic fact of economics*?

Which of these two is most appropriate and why?

Answer (score 2):

I would prefer the second, as it emphasizes that this is a 'fact' within the mainstream theory of economics. I would use the first version to describe an *observable* fact related to an economy. (I would point out that in a deflationary spiral, the statement may not even turn out to be true. As a 'fact' in an oversimplified version of theory, this is OK. As an observation, nonsensical.)

Comment: Hm, perhaps fact is the wrong word. Maybe principle would be more accurate. What would you suggest?

Comment: I like principle. I think 'general' is a useful qualifier, too. I think the magic phrase, for economists, is _ceteris paribus_.